# C++: Best way to parse a string to a double

Tags: c++, parsing

Lets say I have the following string:

```
string str = "I 500.000 500.000 30000 30.000 60.000 20.000 20.0 60.0 ;"
```

And the following variables:

```
double x1;
double x2;
int x3;
```

And I want to parse the above string so that in the end

```
x1 = 500.000
x2 = 500.000
x3 = 30000
```

What would be the best way to do such parsing? A code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

---

UPDATE

Alright, when I said "best" I actually meant easiest as in when are you are given a sample string as above where you know exactly how the string is formatted. e.g a character followed by two doubles followed by an integer etc... and all I care is the shortest code that is also neat and simple. No need to take care of time and extra data handling.

Comment: I was looking for the best way, not that I don't know how to do this. Its always good to explore other ways of doing this.

Comment: Define "best"?  Fastest?  Least memory?  Least source code?  Least binary size?  Handles the most extra stuff in the string?  `strtod` is very good at this.

Comment: @user44273, If you post what you have and define what you need, it's a lot easier to provide the most relevant information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stringstream fits your needs:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(str);
iss.get(); //'I'

if (iss >> x1 >> x2 >> x3) {
    //success
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using stringstream as follows:

```
string str = "I 500.000 500.000 30000 30.000 60.000 20.000 20.0 60.0 ;"
stringstream ss(str);
char c =' ';

ss >>c>> x1 >> x2  >>x3 ;
```